# How to force a new instantiation of a lambda-definition

Tags: java, jvm, inlining

The Java-Spec guarantees that a given lambda-definition, e.g. `() -> "Hello World"`, is compiled/converted to exactly one implementation class (every definition, not every occurence that "looks" the same).

Is there any way I can force the java-compiler/jvm to generate a new lambda-definition instead of sharing a common one? I am currently implementing a library that weaves multiple function parts into a BiFunction which suffers from mega-morphic call-sites because of the guarantees given by the java-spec (**EDIT: I stand corrected: the Java-Spec does not guarantee a single shared class - the current reference implementation does this though**):

```
        public <In, Out, A> BiFunction<In, Out, Out> weave(
             Function<? super In, A> getter,
             BiConsumer<? super Out, ? super A> consumer
        ) {
            return (in, out) -> {
                consumer.accept(out, getter.apply(in));
                return out;
            };
        }
```

Every lambda generated through this code shares the same lambda-definition and is thus mostly uninlineable / unoptimizeable.

Comment: It doesn't looks like you have any luck without some run-time code generation.

Comment: There is a fundamental misconception. Nothing in the specification guarantees that. The specification *allows* to produce the same implementation class, but in fact, it explicitly says that the same lambda expression *may* result in different implementation classes.

Comment: I doubt it will help  `BiConsumer` still remain mega-morphic.

Comment: @Holger I was under the impression section 15.27.4 is guaranteeing this as it says:

`Objects produced by different lambda expressions need not belong to different classes (if the bodies are identical, for example).`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4

Comment: “*Objects produced by different lambda expressions need not belong to different classes*” says that it is allowed for different lambda expression to result in the same class (which does not happen in the reference implementation today). Right the next point says “*Every object produced by evaluation need not belong to the same class (captured local variables might be inlined, for example).*” which is exactly about your scenario. The same lambda expression *may* get evaluated to instances of different classes (which also does not happen in the reference implementation today).

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. Though I still need to find a workaround for the current implementation :)

Comment: @talex each `BiFunction` instance captures exactly one `BiConsumer` instance, always ending up at the same implementation. If you generate a distinct class for every `BiFunction` instance, it would be a perfect monomorphic behavior. But I don’t think that this should be necessary, as the JVM may inline the function code through more than one invocation level into different specialized versions. The key point is the captured `BiConsumer` instance here. Perhaps, specifying `-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields` can make a difference here.

Comment: I added `-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields` to my JMH benchmark and it did not make any difference what so ever

Comment: It would be helpful to know the precise setup, test code and Java version. For JDK 8, raising `-XX:MaxInlineLevel=` (the default is `9`) may have a positive impact, especially with APIs like the Stream API where a lot of adaptation steps are made.

Comment: Do you want to generate a new class each time `weave` is called? You can't do this with a lambda expression, but you may simulate a creation of a new lambda manually with `MethodHandles` and `LambdaMetafactory`.

Comment: @Holger Even if you achieve desired effect you will have multiple implementation of `BiFunction` so JIT won't be able to inline them since you call them thru interface.

Comment: @apangin Are you sure that JIT is able to inline implementation generated by `LambdaMetafactory`?

Comment: @talex the JIT is better than that. If a particular caller always ends up at the same implementation, it may get optimized, even when other callers of the same interface method may end up at other implementations. The notion of “caller” depends on `-XX:MaxInlineLevel` here; it doesn’t have to be the direct caller. The implementation returned by `LambdaMetafactory` is not special in that regard, it’s just one level in a call chain.

Comment: @talex Yes, JIT is able to inline a method call, no matter how the class of this method is generated. Actually, static lambda expressions are instantiated using the very same `LambdaMetafactory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current implementation, the caching of generated classes (or even instances for the non capturing lambda expressions), is a property of the [`invokedynamic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokedynamic) instruction which will reuse the result of the bootstrapping done on the first execution.

The bootstrap method itself, hosted in the [`LambdaMetafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) class will generate a new class each time it is invoked. So when you use this factory directly, you’ll get a new class on each invocation, under the current implementation.

```
public <In, Out, A> BiFunction<In, Out, Out> weave(
     Function<? super In, A> getter,
     BiConsumer<? super Out, ? super A> consumer) {

    MethodHandles.Lookup l = MethodHandles.lookup();
    try {
        MethodHandle target = l.findStatic(l.lookupClass(), "weaveLambdaBody",
            MethodType.methodType(Object.class, Function.class, BiConsumer.class,
                Object.class, Object.class));
        MethodType t = target.type().dropParameterTypes(0, 2);
        return (BiFunction<In, Out, Out>)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(l, "apply",
            target.type().dropParameterTypes(2, 4).changeReturnType(BiFunction.class),
            t, target, t) .getTarget().invokeExact(getter, consumer);
    }
    catch(RuntimeException | Error e) {
        throw e;
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(t);
    }
}
private static <In, Out, A> Out weaveLambdaBody(
    Function<? super In, A> getter,
    BiConsumer<? super Out, ? super A> consumer,
    In in, Out out) {

    consumer.accept(out, getter.apply(in));
    return out;
}
```

First, you have to desugar the lambda body into a method. The captured values come first in its parameter list, followed by the parameters of the functional interface type. The [`LambdaMetafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) has an exhaustive documentation about its usage.

While I kept the type parameters for documentation purposes, it should be clear that you lose the compile-time safety here, with such an operation.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine (with some adjustments as `MethodHandles.lookup()` doesn't return the right class when implementing an interface in enum constants separately). My current test-suite indicates that the inlining works fine with this approach or the one in my question (when there is one callsite). I have some other strange performance issues that don't seem to be related to inlining now. Thanks for your help!