# Avoiding megamorphic callsites in Function.andThen

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jit, inlining

Looking at `Function.andThen`:

```java
    default <V> Function<T, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(after);
        return (T t) -> after.apply(apply(t));
    }
```

As this function offers great value it's used extensively which turns its returned function into a pretty bad megamorphic callsite (in the current OpenJDK11 implementation). Even when resorting to manually instantiating a lambda via `LamdaMetafactory` (see the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920520/how-to-force-a-new-instantiation-of-a-lamda-definition)) all the generated lambdas share the same body and therefor the same byte-code-index which is (as I am aware of) used to keep the type-profile data of callsites which makes it megamorphic again.

Is there any reasonable way to achieve a non-megamorphic `andThen` **without**:

- compile-time code-generation via build-system plugins
- runtime code-generation that is not supported on J9, OpenJDK Hotspot and Graal

Comment: "runtime code-generation that is not supported on J9, OpenJDK Hotspot and Graal" ? You mean you don't want to use e.g. ASM?

Comment: As far as I am aware Graal does not support any kind of runtime code generation, so `ASM`, `Javassist`, `Unsafe` etc. seem unuseable (will gladly be corrected if this is wrong) - so the answer is yes

Comment: Well, AFAIK that limitation only applies to SubstrateVM, i.e. what's used for `native-image` (but I'm not 100% on that). But yeah, as you say, profiles are indexed by method + bci, so the only way to get more profiles is to spin more code :) Or wait for: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8015416

Comment: Waiting on a 6 year old issue it is then...? Thanks anyway... My Graal wording was a bit off, I was of course also talking about `SubstrateVM` (I just want to support every JVM). Seems strange that such a big performance oppurtunity was not tackled in such a long time even if its hard to do

Comment: You can not combine static compilation with monomorphic behavior for a method that can produce an infinite number of function combinations. So `SubstrateVM` is ruled out in principle.

Comment: Given the possibility to reinstantiate `andThen`s body (or returned function) and thus generating a new function with a separate type profile would allow this though. The above linked bug would resolve my issue

Comment: But that’s an issue for JVMs with dynamic compilation anyway. For a JVM with static compilation, any way of adding new code must be forbidden or lead to an embedded interpreter or dynamic fallback. For JVMs which support adding code, generating the class on the fly would be easy, for all others, this is not an issue anyway. The linked bug also is specific to a particular JVM implementation. It doesn’t say that other JVMs have that problem at all.

Comment: You are correct but given the right circumstances (e.g. a long `andThen`-chain defined as a `static`) would even allow `SubstrateVM` to optimize this as all type information is present in a `static` context. I don't know if `SubstrateVM` currently employs such optimization, but it is theoretically possible as a `static` definition is strictly monomorphic (after simple resolution steps)

Comment: 1. Are you sure that the megamorphic call is the real performance issue in your case? How did you find that? 2. Even if it is a real (not theoretical) problem, you could probably work around it for your particular case by replacing `andThen` call with the inlined code.

Comment: 1. Yes, I found that while looking at the `PrintInling, PrintCompilation` logs. Simple getter-setter chains suffer immensely compared to manual inlining / a manual implementation

  2. This is about a library wherein the user defines the `andThen`chains (simplification of whats actually happening) so this isn't an option

Comment: Well, if you care about nanosecond performance, the functional approach, stream API etc. is probably not a good choice in the first place. I mean, if user creates andThen chains of function objects, then... there is already a trouble, and it's not in the authority of the library to do anything about it.

Comment: @roookeee well yes, `SubstrateVM` could perform such optimizations, but this is outside your control. Either it has such optimizations or it hasn’t. Your question is about a fix for a particular behavior of a particular JVM implementation which *does* support adding code.

Comment: I disagree somewhat as this does not seem like an unsolveable problem (see the linked bug ticket and my reasoning about `static`) and libraries (subjectively) should be inclined to have the least overhead as possible. There is more and more reliance on smart compilers these days but wasting avoidable cycles in a library seems rough (to me)

Comment: Thanks for your input, Holger, apangin, Jorn Vernee - this seems resolved to me :) I was looking for a way to do this myself across multiple (all) JVMs which just isn't possible with the constraints I have mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the simplest and least resource consuming solution is to wait until [JDK-8015416](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8015416) gets fixed.

As a work-around, we may produce new distinct classes.

If we limit the approach to certain well-known operations like combining two `Function` instances via `andThen`, spinning a new class for each request is quiet easy to achieve, with standard APIs and no need to perform bytecode magic:

```
public final class FunctionCombinator<T,U,R> implements Function<T,R> {
    final Function<? super T,? extends U> first;
    final Function<? super U,? extends R> second;

    public FunctionCombinator(
        Function<? super T,? extends U> f1, Function<? super U,? extends R> f2) {
        first = f1;
        second = f2;
    }

    @Override
    public R apply(T t) {
        return second.apply(first.apply(t));
    }

    @Override
    public <V> Function<T, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
        return newCombinator(this, after);
    }

    @Override
    public <V> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before) {
        return newCombinator(before, this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <A,B,C> Function<A,C> newCombinator(
        Function<? super A,? extends B> f1, Function<? super B,? extends C> f2) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(f1);
        Objects.requireNonNull(f2);

        URL u = FunctionCombinator.class.getProtectionDomain()
            .getCodeSource().getLocation();
        try(URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { u }, null)) {
            return cl.loadClass(FunctionCombinator.class.getName())
                .asSubclass(Function.class)
                .getConstructor(Function.class, Function.class)
                .newInstance(f1, f2);
        }
        catch(IOException | ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This code simply re-reads the class definition of `FunctionCombinator` in a new class loader having the bootstrap loader as its parent, which prevents it from resolving to the already existing class.

The hidden costs associated with such a class loader are implementation dependent. Note that this code closes the loader after loading the single class to cut down the allocated resources. If the particular JVM supports class unloading, the loader of a function combinator may get garbage collected when the function is not used anymore.

Of course, environments with static compilation, not supporting the addition of new classes won’t support this. For those environments, you have to rely on the capabilities of static code analysis anyway. You may make this class generation optional, to avoid failures in these environments:

```
static final boolean CREATE_NEW_CLASSES = Boolean.getBoolean("generateNewClassForAndThen");

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <A,B,C> Function<A,C> newCombinator(
    Function<? super A,? extends B> f1, Function<? super B,? extends C> f2) {

    Objects.requireNonNull(f1);
    Objects.requireNonNull(f2);

    if(!CREATE_NEW_CLASSES) return new FunctionCombinator<>(f1, f2);

    URL u = FunctionCombinator.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    try(URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { u }, null)) {
        return cl.loadClass(FunctionCombinator.class.getName()).asSubclass(Function.class)
            .getConstructor(Function.class, Function.class)
            .newInstance(f1, f2);
    }
    catch(IOException | ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
}
```

Then, you need to specify `-DgenerateNewClassForAndThen=true` on the command line to activate this feature.

If you want to consume less resources, you’d have to resort to `Unsafe`…

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough answer! Will definitely give this a shot. I have one more question though as I don't know much about the beast that is classloading and `ClassLoaders`: Is unloading a class loader which loaded a class not a problem? I assumed classes loaded by an unloaded classloader get unloaded too. And could you go in more detail about: `The hidden costs associated with such a class loader are implementation dependent` in the context that all this is only done once (e.g. in a `static` context / initializer)

Comment: Applying this method at one out of two possible places increased the performance by 100% (twice as fast now). I like the simplistic approach without resorting to byte-code libs :)

Comment: A class loader and all the classes it defined can only get collected together. It’s like a class loader having references to all classes it created and all created classes having a reference to the defining class loader. Here, it’s rather simple, one class and one class loader referring to each other. There might be an overhead due to resources a JVM creates in advance when a new class loader is created. But if you create all combinations during the initialization anyway, the overhead is easy to measure.

Comment: I’m glad that it helped. Care must be taken to keep this `FunctionCombinator` class as simple as it is, i.e. there must be no dependencies between this class and other classes of the application, as the copies of the class can only access bootstrap classes.

Comment: Applying this at every sane location in my code improved the overall performance from 1x to 3x the speed. I still struggle whether to include these changes or not as I cannot estimate how big of an impact and in what sense this has - it's quite hacky and unusual :) Applying it everywhere would likely yield a 4x speedup which is within 20% of manual procedural code which is quite impressive (we are talking about millions of op/s in JMH)

Comment: Well, you might have heard this, every feature is a bug unless you can turn it off. At the end of my answer is a solution that activates this feature only when requested explicitly. The JVM usually is very good at handling `static final boolean` fields, so making it optional does not bear additional costs…

Comment: Is there some way to do this without re-loading a class for every time I do this? I feel like creating hundreds of classloaders with only one class with only one function is quite the overhead

Comment: As said in the last sentence of the answer, there’s `Unsafe`. When defining anonymous classes, the’re not referenced by the class loader and hence, there can be an arbitrary number of classes with the same name. Otherwise, you’d need bytecode processing to change the name of the class, to define multiple incarnations within the same class loader. That’s not too hard for such a narrowed task, it could even be done without 3rd party libraries, but you wanted to avoid that…

Comment: Missed the last sentence. But isn't `Unsafe` near EOL ? I just don't want to invest into a method that won't be supported in the near future (e.g. next LTS release). Have been looking into dynamic proxies but they cache the generated class...

Comment: I’m not advertising `Unsafe`. I suppose, before it gets removed, either, an official replacement for `defineAnonymousClass` will exist or the type pollution problem has been fixed anyway. Until then, a fallback strategy might be used, i.e. if unsafe is not available, use the multiple class loader strategy. Or resort to changing the byte code. The invest would be a few lines of code…

Comment: As an addition, the alternative to `Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass` [is on the way](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8205939)…

Comment: Wouldn't using `Classloader.defineClass` be more preferable over `Unsafe`? It looks like it's implemented as `native` and (just a guess) probably delegates to `Unsafe` which when it gets replaced would work for me as `ClassLoader.defineClass` would probably delegate to the new implementation. I only have to handle VMs which can't call `ClassLoader.defineClass` then (like SubstrateVM)

Comment: That’s what the code of my answer already does, `loadClass` ends up at `defineClass`, there is no need to change anything if you want that. But then, you have to create a new `ClassLoader` each time, as you can’t have more than one class with the same name. That’s the whole point of the unsafe alternative, it allows to define *anonymous* classes whose name is irrelevant, hence you wouldn’t need a new class loader each time. The only other alternative is to generate a new name each time, which requires dealing with the bytecode.

Comment: EDIT: nvm, read your comment wrong. But `defineClass` lets me pass a name, is it not overriding the read class name?

Comment: No, the name passed to `defineClass` is the expected class name for verification. It will throw a `VerifyError` when there is a mismatch.

Comment: I know this is not the right place to do code reviews but is [this](https://pastebin.com/TPvc7J65) abstraction fine by you? Is there any pitfall I am missing? (naming is not final yet)

Comment: It’s dangerous to allow it for arbitrary `Class`es. As explained, there are significant constraints on the class to copy. But at least, you’re limiting the potential callers. Note that starting with Java 9, there’s a better alternative. Further, the generic signature will break. The copy is a distinct class, not equal to the original one, so you can’t make the cast. You need something like `public static <I, T extends I> I newCTPInstance(Class<I> commonInterface, Class<T> implementationToCopy, Object... ctorArgs)` and `cl.loadClass(implementationToCopy.getName()).asSubclass(commonInterface)`…

Comment: Thanks, already noticed that I need an interface type and added it accordingly. As I still want to support Java 8 I will stick to this solution for now. As I am limiting the callers to my own library it's only me that has to be careful. I am measuring the memory impact now

Comment: Creating 10000 unique instances of the functional classes `Function` and `BiFunction` amounts to a total of 17MB additional MetaSpace on OpenJDK11 - this seems fine to me as 10000 is a limit any sane usage of my library won't hit

Answer (score 1):

To anyone interested in how the results of the provided answer by Holger may be applied in more varied ways have a look at [this](https://github.com/roookeee/datus/blob/fe0239beff96902d772bb623e7f92c68f1587b25/src/main/java/com/github/roookeee/datus/shared/LambdaHelper.java) class (it's in a WIP state).